# Variável privada sendo adicionada a sessão automaticamente php

Tags: php, session

Vou tentar explicar o problema, porém, já adianto que não achei nem palavras para pesquisar o ocorrido:

Tenho um arquivo **usuario.php**

```
<?php

    class Usuario{

        private $grupoPermissao = array(
                'superAdmin' => array(
                    'rodrigo_segatto','tiago_silva'
                )
        );

        function __construct(){
            session_start();
        }

        public function getGrupoPermissao(){
            return $this->grupoPermissao;
        }

        public function verificaUsuario(){
            if (!$this->usuarioEstaLogado()){
                $flash = new Flash();
                $flash->setFlash('Você não deve fazer login antes de acessar a página!','alert-danger');
                header('Location:../../View/Sistema/login.php');
                die();
            }
        }

    }
```

O arquivo **processa-login.php**, que redireciona para a index:

```
$flash = new Flash();
$flash->setFlash('Você efetuou login com sucesso!', 'alert-success');
header("Location:../../View/Sistema/index.php");
```

E o arquivo index.php, com o seguinte início de código:

```
<?php 
    require_once '../../AutoLoad.php'; 
    $usuario = new Usuario(); $usuario->verificaUsuario(); 
?>
```

No index, se eu iniciar a sessão antes de dar New no Usuario, e imprimir o SESSION, irá imprimir:

```
Array
(
    (
        [usuario] => rodrigo_segatto
        [email] => rodrigo_segatto@...
        [nome] => RODRIGO SEGATTO
    )
)
```

Caso contrário, se imprimir o SESSION após dar New no usuário, irá criar um objeto dentro com minha variável privada **grupoPermissao**, conforme vemos abaixo:

```
Array
(
    [usuario] => Usuario Object
        (
            [grupoPermissao:Usuario:private] => Array
                (
                    [superAdmin] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => rodrigo_segatto
                            [1] => tiago_silva
                        )
                )

        )

    [email] => rodrigo_segatto@unimedmissoes.com.br
    [nome] => RODRIGO SEGATTO
)
```

O mais estranho que o mesmo sistema funciona perfeitamente **local**, porém, no servidor **linux** ocorre isto.

Comment: Ambas versões do php são iguais? A diretiva "register_globals" no php.ini está como "off"?

Comment: No servidor está "On" e local "Off". Será que é isto então?

Comment: Pode ser, desabilita para testar. Em versões mais novas do PHP já vem desabilitado, qual sua versão e a qual do servidor?

Comment: Então, deve ser isto mesmo, e descobri que esta bagunça era causada quando o nome da classe é o mesmo armazenado na session. EX: class Usuario{ == $_SESSION['usuario'] . Então troquei o nome das variáveis que vão para a sessão e funcionou.

Comment: Bom que deu certo. Mas para não correr o risco de criar uma variavel com o mesmo nome e sobrescrever é legal desativar. Abs